# generate successors with a list of operators

Tags: lisp

the program is working for 2 `operators` and there is more but I just used the `empty-a` and `empty-b` to test the function, when I used single operator but if I used the list of operators return `nil`

```
;;the function no-test
(defun no-test()
  (list '(2 2) 0 nil))

;; the function operators
(defun operators()
  (list 'empty-a 'empty-b))

;; the function create node
(defun create-node (bucket &optional (g 0) (father nil))
  (list bucket g father))

;; the function dfs
(defun dfs (no sucessors)
  (list (append no (car sucessors))))

;; the function bfs
(defun bfs (no sucessors)
  (list (append (car sucessors) no)))

;;operator empty-a
(defun empty-a (state)
  (cond 
   ((> (car state) 0)
    (list 0 (cadr state)))))

;; operator empty-b
(defun empty-b (state)
  (cond 
   ((> (cadr state) 0)
    (list (car state) 0))))
```

this function to generate `successors-aux1`, is working perfectly for single operator like `(sucessors-aux1 (no-test) 'empty-a)` or `(sucessors-aux1 (no-test) 'empty-b)` and [see test in Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/t77Eex)

```
;; the function sucessors aux1
(defun sucessors-aux1 (no operator)
  (print operator);; to show operator
  (cond 
   ((create-node
     (funcall (symbol-function operator) (first no))
     (+ (second no) 1) no))
   (t (sucessors-aux1 no operator))))
```

this function `sucessors` is diferent like `sucessors-aux1` because 
`sucessors` receive a `list` of operators like `(sucessors (no-test) (operators) 'bfs nil)` or `(sucessors (no-test) (operators) 'dfs 2)` and should return all `sucessors-aux1` but return `nil` [see the test in Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/t77Eex)

```
;; the function sucessors  
(defun sucessors (no operator algoritm depth)
  (cond 
   ((equal algoritm 'bfs)
    (loop for x in operator 
        do (sucessors-aux1 no x)))
   ((equal algoritm 'dfs)
    (loop for y in operator
        do (sucessors-aux1 no y)))
   (t (sucessors no operator algoritm depth))))
```

Any suggest?

Comment: The program has bad formatting and many basic mistakes. For example: what is `(and (= depth nil))` supposed to do? There are good introductory books for Lisp. Maybe start there? https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: @RainerJoswig, In fact, there is an error in formatting, but this is irrelevant and the code has already been corrected and if I am putting doubts here in the forum it is logical that I'm a beginner in Lisp and thanks for the books

Comment: If you see errors in formatting please fix them.  Especially the last two functions should be better formatted. Incorrectly formatted code is a pain and provokes errors.

Comment: The `successors` function makes no sense. The first cond clauses are doing the same, and the third creates an endless loop. Maybe you should debug your code first so that it does something useful, before you post it here?

Comment: ok, I will debug before post here and maybe you right about `sucessors`

Comment: I will try to fix them